How to set Unity Vivox Access Token in C# code
We`re using Vivox service & Unity Authentication service in our game. the problem is in some countries the authentication service is out of reach maybe because of sanctions of the US on those countries.
Now we have two options to do so:

Use Vivox in Test Mode to keep the Access Token inside of the code which is very unsafe.
Set Unity Vivox credentials inside the code after the user authenticated in our own user base but we couldn't do it with Vivox SDK ^16

We are completely confused about this challenge and do not know if the other authentication methods of Unity are the same as the under one:
        await UnityServices.InitializeAsync();

        await AuthenticationService.Instance.SignInAnonymouslyAsync(); //Our problem is this line of code
        await VivoxService.Instance.InitializeAsync();

We`re open to any ideas or new options.

            if (UnityServices.State == ServicesInitializationState.Uninitialized)
            {
                await UnityServices.InitializeAsync(new InitializationOptions().SetVivoxCredentials(
                    "server", "domain",
                    "issuer",
                    "token key"));
                await VivoxService.Instance.InitializeAsync();
                LoginOptions options = new LoginOptions();
                options.DisplayName = data.name;
                options.EnableTTS = false;
                // options.PlayerId = data.id.ToString();
                await VivoxService.Instance.LoginAsync(options);
            }
            else if (UnityServices.State== ServicesInitializationState.Initializing)
            {
                Debug.Log("Initiating");
            }

